# I am stuck on this React Testdome question

Tags: reactjs

This is super bugging me - this is a question from TestDome React and I am stuck - could anyone please give me a hand? Thanks in advance!  (this is the link:  https://www.testdome.com/d/react-js-interview-questions/304)
This is the question:

This application should allow the user to update their username by inputting a custom value and clicking the button.

The Username component is finished and should not be changed, but the App component is missing parts. Finish the App component so that the Username component displays the inputted text when the button is clicked.

The App component should use the React.useRef Hook to pass the input to the Username component for the input element and for the Username component.

For example, if the user inputs a new username of "John Doe" and clicks the button, the div element with id root should look like this:

```
<div><button>Change Username</button><input type="text"><h1>John Doe</h1></div>
```

```
// React is loaded and is available as React and ReactDOM
// imports should NOT be used
class Username extends React.Component {
  state = { value: "" };

  changeValue(value) {
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return <h1>{value}</h1>;
  }
}

function App() {
  function clickHandler() {}

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change Username</button>
      <input type="text" />
      <Username />
    </div>
  );
}

document.body.innerHTML = "<div id='root'></div>";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

document.querySelector("input").value = "John Doe";
document.querySelector("button").click();
setTimeout(() => console.log(document.getElementById("root").innerHTML));
```

Comment: So what part of that snippet is the test question and what part is your attempt? You also neglected to mention what you are struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update the App component to be like that

```
function App() {
  let userRef = React.useRef();
  let inputRef = React.useRef('');

  function clickHandler() {
    userRef.current.changeValue(inputRef.current.value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change Username</button>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <Username ref={userRef}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @samhanwar - I haven't used React for a few years (been using Vue) but need to do a React Dome test... :(.